# Using a second select statement in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use a second Select statement in my SQL query but the table in my application is not displaying the values TAGS_DELIMITED  from the second select statement. I'm getting "A field or property with the name 'TAGS_DELIMITED' was not found on the selected data source." The second select statement works fine when executed alone, and the first as well, but it's not working when they are together like below.

The data is as follows:

```
ORDERS:
ORDER_ID    FIRST_NAME  Active
300         Barney      Y

TAGS:
TAG_ID  TAGS
1       ORANGES
2       APPLES

TaggedOrders
ORDER_ID    TAG_ID
300         1
300         2

The final results of the table should display:
Order ID    First Name  Tags
1           Barney      ORANGES,APPLES
```

Search term "Barney"

And SQL Stored Proc:

```
        @Keyword varchar (200)
        ,@IsActive varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT ORDERS.ORDER_ID AS [ORDER_ID], First_Name AS [First_Name]           

        FROM ORDERS     

    LEFT JOIN TaggedOrders
    ON ORDERS.ORDER_ID = TaggedOrders.ORDER_ID
    LEFT JOIN Tags
    ON TAGS.TAG_ID = TaggedOrders.TAG_ID
    WHERE ORDERS.First_Name LIKE '%'+@Keyword+'%' and Orders.Active = @IsActive

SELECT STUFF((
       SELECT ','+Tags.TAGS
       FROM Tags
       left join TaggedOrders
       on TaggedOrders.TAG_ID = tags.TAG_ID
       left join ORDERS
       ON TaggedOrders.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID
       where Orders.First_Name = @Keyword
       FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1, '') AS [TAGS_DELIMITED]  

END
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but if you are actually looking for your result to be a table with three columns, you should not have two select statements. Even if this did execute, you would be looking at one table with two columns named [ORDER_ID], [First_Name] followed by one table with one column named [TAGS_DELIMITED]. Since you're not actually selecting from a table in your second select (sub-query aside) you should be able to include that whole STUFF function and alias within the select clause of the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Thermos for the suggestion. This works:

```
        @Keyword varchar (200)
        ,@IsActive varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT ORDERS.ORDER_ID AS [ORDER_ID], First_Name AS [First_Name],
STUFF((
       SELECT ','+Tags.TAGS
       FROM Tags
       left join TaggedOrders
       on TaggedOrders.TAG_ID = tags.TAG_ID
       left join ORDERS
       ON TaggedOrders.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID
       where Orders.First_Name = @Keyword
       FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1, '') AS [TAGS_DELIMITED]           

        FROM ORDERS     

    LEFT JOIN TaggedOrders
    ON ORDERS.ORDER_ID = TaggedOrders.ORDER_ID
    LEFT JOIN Tags
    ON TAGS.TAG_ID = TaggedOrders.TAG_ID
    WHERE ORDERS.First_Name LIKE '%'+@Keyword+'%' and Orders.Active = @IsActive  

END
```